# How to import a js file and use it in angular library (not in project)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openseadragon

I am developing image zoom in angular4 library,I need to import openseadragon js file to my library.

If it is angular project then simply i can add cdn to index.html, but in library how can i import js file.

I tried with the angular-cli.json file in the below way, but it didn't worked.

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js"
]
```

Any solutions will be appreciated..

Comment: Try to import it  (if you are using commonJs) Import * as openseadragon from 'openseadragon'.If it is not available, try to install @types and do the same

Comment: @types in not available for openseadragon..

Comment: I tried next steps and this works: 
1. Added  "openseadragon": "2.3.0" to the package.json
2. npm install
3. import * as test from 'openseadragon'; and this works fine. 

Ts 2.4.1.
VS Code

Comment: @Vitalii It's working perfectly, thank you so much.. :)

Comment: If you do not mind, I will ad this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to do the following (and skip any step you already did)

```
1. Add "openseadragon": "2.3.0" to the package.json.
2. Use npm install.
3. Write in your ts file : import * as dragon from 'openseadragon';
4. Profit :)
```